# Я недавно зашла в галерею посмотреть последнее фото которое было сделано в этом 2023 году. Смотрю на дату а там написано январь 1970 г

Tags: .net

В общем я захотела посмотреть свои первые фотографии которые были сделаны в этом 2023 году. Захожу в галерею и смотрю на дату, и там написано январь 1970 год. Просто чтоб вы понимали меня ещё тогда не было. Я не знаю что это такое по этому если кто знает скажите пожалуйста что это

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не относится к программированию или системному администрированию

Comment: Первое января 1970 - дата от которой отсчитываются даты в компьютерных базах данных. По какой-то причина дата съемки не записалась в галерею, вместо неё ноль, а ноль это 1.1.1970.

Comment: И каким боком это относится к программированию?

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего это просто глюк телефона, так как минимальная дата, которую можно поставить как раз 1 января 1970